# Logs Rollover unexpectedly on heavy logging

Tags: file-io

I have an application that contain some set of 20 daemons always running and I have set logging\tracing on all the processes and sometimes during start of the services , I see that logs rollover unexpectedly before the fixed size. I mean that if a log file maximum size is set to some 20 MB and during the start up of services some times some of the logs have size less than 20 MB and result in creation of new log file.

Please can some one kindly provide the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Persistence.

Comment: What services? Windows services with WCF Tracing? If so, msdn says that the actual message size can differ.

Comment: while re-starting the services of an application in services.msc

Comment: you may check the online-documentation. I think there is something written about the logs there.